# TypeError: str.replace is not a function when using proxy object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, proxy, lazy-initialization

I have a TypeScript class that extends an abstract class called Lazy. The Lazy class uses a proxy object to get and set properties dynamically. Here is the code:

```
abstract class Lazy<T> {
  constructor(obj: Partial<T>) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: (t, p) => {
        // cache hit
        if (p in t) return t[p as keyof this];
        // cache miss, get part(s) from getter
        return Object.assign(t, this.get(p));
      },
    });
  }

  protected abstract get(prop: any): any;
}

interface Entry {
  id: number;
}
class Entry extends Lazy<Entry> {
  protected async get(prop: keyof Entry) {}
}

console.log(new Entry({}))
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

`[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:"`

`[ERR]: str.replace is not a function`

I don't understand why I am getting this error, because I am not using the replace function anywhere in my code. I suspect that the error is related to the proxy getter since removing it resolves the error.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the playground's fault...

Comment: I wasn't considering that, but it actually might be. I was originally using this in deno and it was working fine except it would log [object Object] instead of the class name. When investigating this in the playground I faced the said error. Should I submit this as a bug on the Typescript github?

Comment: I tested this on stackblitz and it works. I guess you could/should but it may not be considered since the playground is really just a place to see TypeScript's types in action. It's not really a full-blown IDE with a proper sandboxed JavaScript environment.

Comment: I see. Unrelated to the question but do you know why it logs [object Object] {} in the console?

Comment: I'm not sure why Deno does that. I get `Entry {}` with Node.

Comment: Sorry, disregard that; seems to be a deno issue.